# java find objects with unique attribute in a list

Tags: java

I have a list of objects in the following form

```
Person object with attributes and values
name=x, state=va
name=x, state=nj
name=x, state=va
name=x, state=va
name=x, state=md
name=x, state=va
```

I want to find the unique state values as an array or list. Do Google collection or Java provide this feature? Or do I have to loop through all objects and find the unique state values?

Comment: You *could* loop through them. Or come up with a better way to store your data than a list if that's a common access pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have to loop. The best collection for unique values is a Set, but if you really want a List or an array, you can always tranform the Set afterwards:

```
 Set<String> statesAsSet = new HashSet<String>();
 for (Person p : persons) {
     statesAsSet.add(p.getState());
 }

 // if yo want a list:
 List<String> statesAsList = new ArrayList<String>(statesAsSet);
 // if you want an array:
 String[] statesAsArray = statesAsSet.toArray(new String[statesAsSet.size()]);
```

You should read the [Java collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/). This is a must-know.

Answer (score 4):

The question has been answered a long time ago. For future readers who are using Java 8 or later, you could use the Streams API to find all unique `state` values from a `person` list.

```
List<String> uniqueStates = persons.stream()
            .map(Person::getState)
            .distinct()
            .collect(toList());
```

The key thing to notice here is the [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) operation. From java docs:

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) in your `Personal` class.
2. [Create a `Set`, from the `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28java.util.Collection%29)
3. [Convert the set back to `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

I know you could just loop and compare and do the stuffs as mentioned in other answer. I am just mentioning the method that does not involve loop.

Comment: This unnecessarily changes the equality semantics of the `Person` class, I'd recommend creating a new set of states.

Answer (score 1):

The "functional" way to do this with Guava (Google Collections) might be something like this:

```
Set<State> uniqueStates = Sets.newHashSet(
   Iterables.transform(persons, new Function<Person, State>() {
     @Override public State apply(Person person) {
        return person.getState();
     }
   ));
```